# bitmap size exceeds VM budget...how to solve this error?

Tags: android

I have gone through so many posts related to this error but not getting proper solution for my problem.
there are three activities in my projec..in each acivity there are 4 animations for which i am using sequences. on onclick to change my activity i am getting vm budget out of memory error. 
How to clear memory of an acivity while we are going to other activity? so that memory could be used for next activity..
thanks in advance for help...

Error occuring is as below....

```
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:265)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7393)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at com.bokstverna.InnerActivityR.onCreate(InnerActivityR.java:87)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-10 10:35:12.046: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(472):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: this will solve u r problem:

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966

Answer (score 2):

U have to scale ur bitmap like  below,

```
img.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200,200, true));
```

then its size will not exceed.It will fix to a particular size.

Comment: If I wil scale my image thn quality of my image wil degrade...I dnt wnt to scale my images....wht i want is to free memory when I switch from one activity to next one...at tht time memory used by pre-activity should be freed...